# How to use BeautifulSoup to extract span content with data-reactid?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the `Market Cap` from [this](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TXG?p=TXG&.tsrc=fin-srch) yahoo finance website.

[image]

[image]

I used

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TXG?p=TXG&.tsrc=fin-srch'
wb_data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
cap = soup.find("span", class_ = "Trsdu(0.3s) ").get_text()
print(cap)
```

But I got `80.81` (which is "Previous Close"), instead of `8.01B`. This is because the "Previous Close" shares the same class. So I try to limit the search by using `data-reactid`. How to achieve this?

I got the answer, but it is so strange, it is `attrs = {"data-reactid": "57"}` instead of `139`!

Comment: Sorry the `data-reactid` should be 139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` function treats any unknown keyword argument as an attribute filter, so to find an element whose `id` attribute is `foo`, you'd write:

```
soup.find(id = "foo")
```

You can't use `data-class` as a keyword argument directly, because the hyphen makes it an illegal identifier in Python. But BeautifulSoup [has you covered](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments):

```
cap = soup.find("span", class_ = "Trsdu(0.3s) ", attrs = {"data-reactid": "85"})
```

Note that depending on React IDs is probably very brittle, so it might be better to depend on surrounding elements like that "Market Cap" label instead.

Comment: Thank you. I got `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`, when using `cap = soup.find("span", class_ = "Trsdu(0.3s) ", attrs = {"data-reactid": "139"}).get_text()`

Comment: It is so surprising, it is `attrs = {"data-reactid": "57"}` instead of `139`!

Comment: What you see in your browser's dev tools is not necessarily the original HTML sent by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TXG?p=TXG&.tsrc=fin-srch'
wb_data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(wb_data.text,'lxml')
cap = soup.find("span", class_ = "Trsdu(0.3s) ").get('data-reactid')
print(cap)
```

Comment: I got `16`. Why you do not specify the number for `data-reactid`?